# Setting up execution path in Terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, path

I have no experience with using Terminal but I am trying to install a program msbayes 
(installation instructions [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1enMQaogxOs0RppAmE8KcGU3nNjzotuiycAl6I1s0KYg/edit).

The instructions say to set up an execution path using either

```
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Or

```
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I have tried both of these but am still getting a command not found response. What am I doing wrong? Any advice?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Are you copying the dollar sign into terminal?  The dollar sign in writing, like in the document, is just a sign that it is on a new terminal line.

You can copy and paste these commands into terminal and it should work. I just tried it on my machine

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you can verify that they have worked by typing in this command

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
```

And you should see

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

or

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Depending on which one you used.

If you want the changes to also be applied to the currently running shell, you need to run

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

as well.

Comment: Thanks this seems to have worked but I still then get a "command not found" response when I try to do anything in the program

Comment: Can you copy and paste the command you are running?